# JavaScript get data from array object and put into html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrayobject

I have an object that has data stored in it. I have it where users can select an option, then a list of results appear. The results are links. Once a link is clicked I would like for data about the company to appear as a table. Only thing is I don't know how to make it where once you click on the link JavaScript grabs data from that link and put into the html table that will be displayed. My question is how do I link my html elements to data in an object then allow that data to display in a table? Without changing the direction of my original code.

```
$("#listingResults").html("Business Listings Under Category <strong>" + textNameOfBusinessSelected + "</strong> are: <br/><br/><ul id='listOfBusinesses'><li><a href='javascript-exercise-16.html#bottomOfPage' onclick='clickListingLink()'>" + businessListNames.join("<br/><a href='javascript-exercise-16.html#bottomOfPage' onclick='clickListingLink()'><li>") + "</li></ul>");
} // line closes function


function clickListingLink() {
  // function is for when a link is clicked after list of businesses appear
  $('#listOfBusinesses').on('click','li', function(){     
    clickListingLink(); 
    console.log('you clicked me'); 
    seeListingInfoTable(); 
    $("hr").show();    
  });
}

function seeListingInfoTable(titleOfBusinessSelected, businessLinkSelected) {
  // function is for table that shows info of specific link clicked 
  console.log("apple");
  var tbl = "";
    tbl += '<table class="table table-hover">';
    tbl += '</table>';
      tbl += '<tbody>';
      tbl += '<caption class="listingTitle">' + titleOfBusinessSelected + '</caption>';
      tbl += '<tr>';
      tbl += '<th>Address</th>';
      tbl += '<th>Phone Number</th>';
      tbl += '<th>Website</th>';
      tbl += '<th>Specialty</th>';
      tbl += '</tr>';
      tbl += '<tr>';
      tbl += '<td><div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="fname">' + businessLinkSelected["Address"] + '</div></td>';
      tbl += '<td><div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="fname">' + businessLinkSelected["Phone Number"] + '</div></td>';
      tbl += '<td><div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="fname">' + businessLinkSelected["Website"] + '</div></td>';
      tbl += '<td><div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="fname">' + businessLinkSelected["Specialty"] + '</div></td>';
      tbl += '</tr>';
    tbl += '</tbody>';
    tbl += '</table>';
    $(document).find("#infoTable").html(tbl);
} // line ends seeListingInfoTable function
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to your HTML, e.g., `<a href="#" data-name=" + businessName + " data-address=" + businessAddress +">` and then grab those with the [jQuery .data() method](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

I've created a minimal example showing the logic, so you can implement it in your code.

```js
var $person = $('.person');
var $resultName = $('.result-name');
var $resultAge = $('.result-age');

$person.on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  
  var name = $this.data('name');
  var age = $this.data('age');
  
  $resultName.html(name);
  $resultAge.html(age);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a class="person" href="#" data-name="John Doe" data-age="12">One</a></li>
  <li><a class="person" href="#" data-name="Mark Z" data-age="23">Two</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="result">
  <p>Name: <span class="result-name"></span></p>
  <p>Age: <span class="result-age"></p>
</div>
```